# Grouped UITable with single/multiple and required/optional groups (iOS)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to create a grouped UITable on an iOS app. Some of the groups are optional and some required to have some item selected. Some of those should also allow for multiple selections. I am at complete lost if this can be achieved and how. Any suggestions?

(my table is being populated from a json object which has indication about which section is required and which allows multiple selection)

Comment: Most of what you're trying to do is determined by the structure of your data source. How many sections it has, and whether an item in a particular section is selected would all be based on how your data source is set up. As for multiple selection, that's a property set for the whole table view, but you could use willSelectRowAtIndexPath to deny selection of a row if a row in that section is already selected.

Comment: This got me completely on track. Is simpler than I thought. I am implementing willSelectRowAtIndexPath and I am checking if the section allows for multiple selections or not and change stuff accordingly. Thanks!